# Node.js (Express) Restful API App in Cpanel not working(APIs)? getting 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: node.js, api, express, cpanel

In this case I have mention auth API, other APIs also not working getting same results

In localhost it's working(`server.use('/auth', routeAuth);`)

In server once I created Node app in Cpanel(`server.use('/server/auth', routeAuth);`) which is not working

In server code block below server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const routeAuth = require('./auth/auth');
const routeRegister = require('./auth/register');

const routeArticle = require('./api/article/article');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4300;

server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
server.use(cors());

server.use('/server/auth', routeAuth);
server.use('/server/', routeRegister);

server.use('/server/api', routeArticle);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`));
```

localhost Postman test working
[image]

After deploy to server and the result not working
[image]

Comment: I think you have some error, when you run your project on server, No error occurs?? like do not require some files.js?? do you run your server with `pm2` ?

Comment: Do the other services work properly on server?? and if you send request with `http` what happend?

Comment: No, I didn't use `pm2`
I added `server.get('/server', (req, res) => res.send('getting data'));` in server.js
and I'm getting "getting data" with this API - https://example.com/server/
which mean server is working right but integrated APIs(https://example.com/server/auth/login) are getting 503

Comment: http://example.com/server/auth/login http gives 404

Comment: do you deploy your project on cpanel like this https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-with-cpanel/, No error occurs when started?

Comment: Is the port open on the server? Is there firewall in between?

Comment: Getting error an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined. In my auth.js file 
` router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function (error, tempCont) {
        if (error) {
            tempCont.release();
            console.log('Error: can not connect database');
        }
        else { ......`
@MohammadYaserAhmadi Yes similar to that doc,
@AvivLo Yes it's an open Port

Answer (score 0):

It happened because I had an DB configuration error, solved it with instead of using `tempCont.release();` I omit it and used only the response, by doing this I have solve the error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined`, which caused 503 Service Unavailable. Then after solving DB configuration issue I have again added the `tempCont.release();` now it works fine.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
connection.getConnection((error, tempCont) => {
    if (error) {
        // tempCont.release();
        res.json({ message: 'Can not connect database' });
    }
    else { ....
```